# Same model/same data different results in Keras/TF

Tags: keras, nlp

So first to mention I used for all models the **identical dataset** (just in different shapes).

I started with a binary classification based on text following the tutorial from https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_classification_from_scratch/. The results are quite promising on my dataset at ~80%. Dataset were .txt files generated from the CSV.
[image]

Further I wanted to add additional structured data to increase the accuracy following this tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv#mixed_data_types). But the results were quite bad at ~50%. I then adapted the layers from the first tutorial but the results are still bad. Dataset was CSV directly.
[image]

Now I removed all structured data from the CSV and just left the text in it but the results are not similar. Why? Dataset was CSV directly.
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization
import numpy as np
from typing import Union
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.keras_tensor import KerasTensor

titanic = pd.read_csv("Dataset.csv")
titanic.head()

titanic_features = titanic.copy()
titanic_labels = titanic_features.pop('survived')

inputs = {}

for name, column in titanic_features.items():
  dtype = column.dtype
  if dtype == object:
    dtype = tf.string
  else:
    dtype = tf.float32

  inputs[name] = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name=name, dtype=dtype)
  

numeric_inputs = {name:input for name,input in inputs.items()
                  if input.dtype==tf.float32}

x = layers.Concatenate(name='ConcatNumeric')(list(numeric_inputs.values()))

norm = preprocessing.Normalization(name='PrepNormalization')


norm.adapt(np.array(titanic[numeric_inputs.keys()]))
all_numeric_inputs = norm(x)


# Not adding numeric values to dataset
preprocessed_inputs = []


# Model constants.
max_features = 20000
embedding_dim = 128
sequence_length = 500

# Now that we have our custom standardization, we can instantiate our text
# vectorization layer. We are using this layer to normalize, split, and map
# strings to integers, so we set our 'output_mode' to 'int'.
# Note that we're using the default split function,
# and the custom standardization defined above.
# We also set an explicit maximum sequence length, since the CNNs later in our
# model won't support ragged sequences.
vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=max_features,
    output_mode="int",
    output_sequence_length=sequence_length,
)

for name, input in inputs.items():
  if input.dtype == tf.float32:
    continue
  
  x = vectorize_layer(input)
  x = layers.Embedding(max_features + 1, embedding_dim)(x)
  x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
  x = layers.Conv1D(128, 7, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=3)(x)
  x = layers.Conv1D(128, 7, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=3)(x)
  x = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(name='GlobalMaxPooling')(x)
  x = layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(x)
  x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
  x = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="predictionasds")(x)
  preprocessed_inputs.append(x)


titanic_preprocessing = tf.keras.Model(inputs, preprocessed_inputs)

titanic_preprocessing.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

titanic_features_dict = {name: np.array(value) 
                         for name, value in titanic_features.items()}

titanic_preprocessing.fit(x=titanic_features_dict, y=titanic_labels, epochs=3)

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model = titanic_preprocessing , rankdir="LR", dpi=72, show_shapes=True)
```

Comment: I solved it in the meanwhile. The Problem is with the input of data, titanic_features_dict had a strange behaviour. If I put in the data as titanic_features['text'] it worked as expected. As well as the "input" of inputs, I change the input from the vectorizing layer to the array in cleartext and it worked.